# MySQL: SELECT query, but then delete records from that query where columns equal

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my initial query:

```
SELECT bid_tag.*
FROM bid_tag join
     (select serial_number, count(*) as cnt
      from bid_tag where user_id = 0
      group by serial_number
     ) tsum
     on tsum.serial_number = bid_tag.serial_number and cnt > 1
order by bid_tag.serial_number
LIMIT 0, 21000;
```

Now from those results, I need to SELECT all where `tag_design = 0 AND tag_size = 0` and then `DELETE` those records from the database.

I just don't know how to run a query on the results of an initial query.

Comment: Why not just do a delete with this query as a subquery?

Comment: Can you show me the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I assume you want to delete records from the `bid_tag` table? If so, what is the PK of that table?

Comment: the primary key id just the `id` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `SELECT` with `DELETE` and it will delete the rows that would have been selected.

```
DELETE bid_tag.*
FROM bid_tag join
     (select serial_number, count(*) as cnt
      from bid_tag where user_id = 0
      group by serial_number
     ) tsum
     on tsum.serial_number = bid_tag.serial_number and cnt > 1
WHERE tag_design = 0 AND tag_size = 0
order by bid_tag.serial_number
LIMIT 0, 21000;
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the rows that have been selected, I need to delete a specific query ON the rows that have been selected.

Comment: @dcolumbus so add that condition in the query itself

Comment: I've added a WHERE clause.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate what you're saying ... but I need to see it with my owns eyes so I can recognize that it will work.

Comment: Apparently you can't use `LIMIT` in a `DELETE` command. It would probably be possible to fix this by moving it into a subquery and then joining. Do you really need the LIMIT option?

Comment: I don't really need the LIMIT, as long as the results are true.

Answer (score 0):

use an `EXISTS` term in your where clause:

```
DELETE
  FROM bid_tag btd
 WHERE EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
             FROM (
                     SELECT bid_tag.*
                       FROM bid_tag bts
                       JOIN (
                               SELECT serial_number, count(*) as cnt
                                 FROM bid_tag btj
                                WHERE btj.user_id = 0
                             GROUP BY btj.serial_number
                            ) tsum
                         ON (     tsum.serial_number = bts.serial_number
                              AND tsum.cnt > 1
                            )
                      WHERE bts.tag_design = 0
                        AND bts.tag_size = 0
                   ORDER BY bts.serial_number
                      LIMIT 0
                          , 21000
                  ) rs_base
            WHERE rs_base.id = btd.id   -- PK column
      )
      ;
```

the subquery in the `EXISTS` term can be nested further to contain another query on the result set of the original one. just make sure that you always select the primary key of the table on which the deletion is to be performed.

note that you probably don't want to restrict yourself to a part of your result set in a delete operation so check whether you need the limiting to the top 21000 results - if you dont, drop the 'ORDER BY' and 'LIMIT' clauses.